# Which sentence is correct and which sentence sounds natural?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference, american-english, passive-voice

"A machine that could be manufactured at low cost". or  "A machine that could manufacture at low cost"

Comment: They convey very different meanings. The first sentence is in regards to its **own creation**, and the second, pertains to what **it can create**. I'm a little iffy on the construction of the second sentence.

Comment: The first is grammatical and meaningful. The second is looking for an object after the verb.

Answer (score 1):

1

> "A machine that could be manufactured at low cost"

2

> "A machine that could manufacture at low cost"

The 2 examples mean different things, as commented.

In (1), the machine is the product; in (2), the product is something else, which should be stated.

2a would be fine.

2a

> "A machine that could manufacture [shirts] at low cost"

Comment: Thank you so much!